# how to array language change with i18n

Tags: javascript, react-native, translation, i18next, react-native-gifted-chat

In my project, I am using the gifted chat and i18n library for change the language and conversation but in gifted chat if we are using the **ONPRESS** funtion and I added the array

```
const options =  ['copy','Delete Message', 'Cancel'];
```

now I want to change the language and I am using below this:

```
const options =  [`${t(strings.copy)}`,'Delete Message', 'Cancel'];
```

but its not working

I try the language change array for mapping and try to condition base array show in android and ios

Comment: can you provide some code to recreate the issue you are facing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: const onLongPress = (context: any, message:any) => {
    const options =  [`${t(strings.copy)}`,`${t(strings.cancel)}`];
    const cancelButtonIndex = options.length - 1;
    context.actionSheet().showActionSheetWithOptions({
        options,
        cancelButtonIndex
    }, (buttonIndex: any) => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
          
            case 0:
              Clipboard.setString(message.text)
                break;
            case 1:
                // onDelete(messageIdToDelete) //pass the function here
                break;
        }
    }
    );
}